# Uninstall AWS CDK Command Line Tool on Ubuntu 20.04.3LTS

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-cdk

UPDATE: Resolved by removing the .nvm folder, closing terminal, and then running npm install -g aws-cdk@2.10.0 again resolved the issue. I hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same problem.

I am trying to upgrade from AWS CDK 1 to 2, but for some reason I am unable to update the [CDK command line tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html) on my machine. No matter what version I install through npm, running `cdk --version` still prints 1.89.0 for me.

So I figured I would just uninstall the CDK and start over. Sadly, that didn't work either.

I've tried both updating and uninstalling globally:

```
13:52 $ npm install -g aws-cdk@2.10.0

added 212 packages, and audited 213 packages in 20s

1 critical severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
13:54 $ cdk --version
1.89.0 (build df7253c)
13:54 $ npm uninstall -g aws-cdk

up to date, audited 1 package in 781ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And locally:

```
14:10 $ npm uninstall aws-cdk

up to date, audited 1 package in 859ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I'm using the following versions:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTE
- Node 16.3.0 through nvm 0.39.1
- npm 8.5.0

I also checked if "cdk" actually refers to a apt-get or snap package, but I didn't see anything when listing all packages with either `snap list` or `apt list --installed`.

Any help greatly appriciated!

Comment: Update: Removing the .nvm folder, closing terminal, and then running npm install -g aws-cdk@2.10.0 again resolved the issue. I hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same problem.

Comment: for me this works fine if you need to remove cdk `sudo npm uninstall -g aws-cdk`

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably is, that you have an old npm global folder lying around, that has an old duplicate cdk version in there.

I had the same issue after moving nodejs from `apt-get` to `nvm`. `nvm` set up a new path to store global npm packages resulting in two different versions of cdk being installed. I removed the old npm global path. Uninstalling .nvm folder in general is a bad solution.

- Run `npm i -g aws-cdk`
- Run `where cdk` to see the installation paths
  for `aws-cdk`.
- If you see more than 1 entry you have duplicate
  installations
- Figure out, which path is the correct one and remove the other paths

Answer (score -1):

[100%] fail: No bucket named ‘cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-########’. Is account ######### bootstrapped?
Cause: CDK requires a staging bucket in S3 containing CDK assets, which may have been removed.

Investigation:

Running aws s3 ls does not yield the bucket.
Fix:

Navigate to the AWS management console

Open CloudFormation

Look for and remove the stack called CDKToolkit

✅ Now re-run cdk bootstrap this will re-generate the staging bucket and the stack CDKToolkit